# Socket in Service + Notification

Tags: java, android, sockets, notifications, android-notifications

I was wondering the other day if it was possible to use the service to keep active sockets, until the destruction of the service?
It 'a very interesting thing that I have not learned well, plus you could add a notification that indicates the status of connection to the socket.
Does anyone have examples to show you if only to understand how a service should be built with the socket?
I thank you in advance

ps: I looked on StackOverflow but I have not found much explanatory examples

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right in assuming that a `Service` is the right tool for the job.

See [**Services | Android Developers**](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html)

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running operations in the background and does not provide a user interface.

Keeping a Socket qualifies for a long-running background operation.

I created this example for you, which does the following:

- Start a `Thread` for connecting / reconnecting and reading the `InputStream` in `onCreate()`
- Report the current connection status in a `Notification`
- Close the `Socket` and stop the `Thread` in `onDestroy()`

**MyService.java**

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationManagerCompat;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class MyService extends Service implements Runnable {

    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;

    private boolean mRunning = false;
    private Thread mThread;

    private Socket mSocket;
    private InputStream mInputStream;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        setNotificationMessage("Service created");

        if (mThread == null) {
            mRunning = true;

            mThread = new Thread(this);
            mThread.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            while (mRunning) {
                try {
                    setNotificationMessage("Connecting");

                    mSocket = new Socket();
                    mSocket.connect(new InetSocketAddress("192.168.56.1", 9899));

                    mInputStream = mSocket.getInputStream();

                    setNotificationMessage("Connected");

                    for (int c = mInputStream.read(); c > -1; c = mInputStream.read()) {
                        setNotificationMessage("Connected: " + (char) c);
                    }
                } catch (UnknownHostException ignored) {
                    setNotificationMessage("Unknown host");
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
                    setNotificationMessage("Disconnected");
                    close();
                }

                try {
                    // Reconnect delay
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
            }
        } finally {
            // Will eventually call onDestroy()
            stopSelf();
        }
    }

    private void setNotificationMessage(CharSequence message) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        builder.setContentTitle("Connection status");
        builder.setContentText(message);

        NotificationManagerCompat nm = NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);
        nm.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }

    private void close() {
        if (mInputStream != null) {
            try {
                mInputStream.close();
                mInputStream = null;
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }

        if (mSocket != null) {
            try {
                mSocket.close();
                mSocket = null;
            } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        if (mThread != null) {
            mRunning = false;

            close();

            while (true) {
                try {
                    mThread.interrupt();
                    mThread.join();
                    mThread = null;
                    break;
                } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
                }
            }
        }

        setNotificationMessage("Service destroyed");

        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Comment: Join will wait for the thread to finish executing, see [Thread | Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#join())

Comment: Do you have demo sample android client socket listener.
Can you check my source. I have Socket server and client android app. I make app to work foreground, It works fine but I think I have some problems with connection. I just need client to listen on incoming messages or notification from server. And i can't connect more than one device to server, either if i stop the app I need to restart the server so I can connect again. Please can you suggest where I make mistake, how to fix this. I just started using java :)
Project:
https://filebin.net/5qnyuat9001wq7ax/SocketExample.zip?t=5nle0onr